# How to save/load to/from file in virtualtree component using Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have downloaded the virtualtree component and the manual"Virtual TreeView tutorial". I follow the tutorial and coding  step  by step. Most of the function in tutorial is fine except the savetofile and loadfromfile do not work.

My node data is

```
type
  PMytreedata = ^TMYTreeData;
  TMYTreeData = record
    Column0: String;
    Column1: String;
    Column2: String;
  end;
```

The question is something string lose in column0,column1/2 when load from file.

The code is below

Create new node and data:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); //CRETAE NEW NODE AND DATA
begin
  Randomize;
  Rand := Random(99);
  XNode := VST.AddChild(nil);

  if VST.AbsoluteIndex(XNode) > -1 then
  begin
    Data := VST.GetNodeData(Xnode);
    Data^.Column0 := IntToStr(Rand)+EDIT1.Text + 'One' ;
    Data^.Column1 := EDIT1.Text+'Two' + IntToStr(Rand + 10);
    Data^.Column2 := EDIT1.Text+'Three' + IntToStr(Rand - 10);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);//ADDCHILD
var
  XNode: PVirtualNode;
  Data: PMytreedata;
begin
  if not Assigned(VST.FocusedNode) then
     Exit;

   XNode := VST.AddChild(VST.FocusedNode);
   Data := VST.GetNodeData(Xnode);

   Data^.Column0 := EDIT1.Text ;
   Data^.Column1 := EDIT2.Text ;
   Data^.Column2 := EDIT3.Text ;

   VST.Expanded[VST.FocusedNode] := True;
end;
```

Save to file  and load from file

```
procedure TForm3.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    VST.SaveToFile('C:\vst.at1');
end;

procedure TForm3.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    VST.LoadFromFile('C:\vst.at1');
end;
```

Get the node size without the code error

```
procedure TForm3.VSTGetNodeDataSize(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  var NodeDataSize: Integer);
begin
    NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TMYTreeData);//WITHOUT THE CODE,ERROR COMING .
end;
```

Show text

```
procedure TForm3.VSTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
  Data: PMytreedata;
begin
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);
  case Column of
    0: CellText := Data^.Column0;
    1: CellText := Data^.Column1;
    2: CellText := Data^.Column2;
  end;
end;
```

LOAD FORM FILE

```
procedure TForm3.VSTLoadNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Stream: TStream);//LOAD FORM FILE
var
  Data: PMytreedata;
  Len: Integer;
begin
      Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);

      Stream.read(Len, SizeOf(Len));
      SetLength(Data^.Column0, Len);
      Stream.read(PChar(Data^.Column0)^, Len);

      Stream.read(Len, SizeOf(Len));
      SetLength(Data^.Column1, Len);
      Stream.read(PChar(Data^.Column1)^, Len);

      Stream.read(Len, SizeOf(Len));
      SetLength(Data^.Column2, Len);
      Stream.read(PChar(Data^.Column2)^, Len);
end;
```

SAVE TO FILE

```
procedure TForm3.VSTSaveNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Stream: TStream); //SAVE TO FILE
var
  Data: PMytreedata;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(Node);

  Len := Length(Data^.Column0);
  Stream.write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
  Stream.write(PChar(Data^.Column0)^, Len);

  Len := Length(Data^.Column1);
  Stream.write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
  Stream.write(PChar(Data^.Column1)^, Len);

  Len := Length(Data^.Column2);
  Stream.write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
  Stream.write(PChar(Data^.Column2)^, Len);
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Unicode Delphi, 2009 and later, `Char` is a 16 bit type, `WideChar`. You are only writing half of the string because you don't account for this. In each call to `Write` and `Read` for the content of the string, you must write twice as many bytes.

For instance, each line like this

```
Stream.read(PChar(Data^.Column0)^, Len);
```

should be

```
Stream.read(PChar(Data^.Column0)^, Len*SizeOf(Char));
```

Some other comments:

- You replicate code to read and write each string. It would be better practise to extract those repeated sections of code into methods for re-use.
- You should use `WriteBuffer` rather than `Write`. `WriteBuffer` calls `Write` to do the work, but also checks the return value and performs error checking. Likewise call `ReadBuffer` rather than `Read`.

Comment: i don't have the experience of using writebuffer. i test it and it work fine.thanks for your for fast and accurate solution.  thanks